# Unexplained error from MediaPlayer

Tags: android

My code tries to play an MP3 file from res/raw.

Code:

```
FileDescriptor fd = appContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.ringtone)
                    .getFileDescriptor();
player = new MediaPlayer();
            try
            {
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                player.setDataSource(fd);
                player.prepare();           
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                player = null;
                return;
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                player = null;
                return;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                player = null;
                return;
            }

            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
```

The log shows:

02-21 15:18:18.360: ERROR/PlayerDriver(51): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported
02-21 15:18:18.380: ERROR/MediaPlayer(693): error (1, -4)
02-21 15:18:18.390: WARN/PlayerDriver(51): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete

After player.prepare() is called.

I really don't have a hint.
I won't use MediaPlayer.create() because I need player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING );

Would appreciate any help on this...

Comment: Did you try with a different file?

Comment: I can play the same file with MediaPlayer.create() so I know it's not a format problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`MediaPlayer` API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> When a `MediaPlayer` object is just
>   created using new or after `reset()`
>   is called, it is in the *Idle* state;
>   and after `release()` is called, it is
>   in the *End* state. Between these two
>   states is the life cycle of the
>   `MediaPlayer` object.
>
> It is a **programming error** to
>   invoke methods such as
>   `getCurrentPosition()`, `...` ,
>   `setAudioStreamType(int)` in the Idle
>   state.

You should study the `MediaPlayer` lifecycle diagram and provided examples and rewrite your code with respect to them. In this case, you see you need to call `setDataSource()` ***before*** `setAudioStreamType()`.

[image]

---

**Side note**: In Android, you really need to follow the lifecycle events for everything you do, or you'll get bitten. You can write incorrect code and you'll never know until runtime, or worse you might write code you think works and you'll only discover in weird circumstances that it doesn't... e.g. the screen orientation changes and the callback method is not the same in this case, or other similar situations (Home button...etc).

Comment: Thanks, but:
1. There's no documentation about the correct lifecycle state for calling setAudioStreamType().
2. I tried what you said already and it gave the same error...

Comment: Sorry, my first sentence isn't true, but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I had similar trouble trying to set the Audio Stream Type and I found this guide helpful:
[API gaps: an Android MediaPlayer example](http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/03/api-gaps-android-mediaplayer-example.html)